# Deploy asp.net on IIS 8

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to deploy a asp.net site on iis 8 but i'm getting an error.

Site is working in visual studio, deployment is done without error using a custom profile with file system as publish method. (Here is actually my first question, should I use file system?)

Build->publish site->(Custom profile, file system, release)

Well, the site is added to selected folder which I've set up in IIS. I host several php pages from this folder whithout problem. But when I try to url forward to the new site I get this error: Given URL returns 500

I'm using IIS8, .tk adress through a dlinkddns.com adress

Any ideas?

Edit: added picture[image]

What should I choose here if i'm hosting the page on the same computer? (I tried File system for now)

The error I get when I'm opening default.aspx
[image]

Comment: It is giving `internal server error`, you might be missing `system.webServer` in web.config , located in deployed location -http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver

Comment: (1) Publish to file system shouldn't be an issue. (2) Is it an IIS error or an ASP.Net error? Is it an ASP.net application (the folder)? Clarify what you meant by "php pages in this folder".

Comment: (1) It is for me =/ (2) I'd have to say asp.net, allthough the site works fine in vs2013. (3) yes. (4) The site is inside  a folder in wwwroot. I have other sites, written in php, in wwwroot which is working. So the IIS is running.

Answer (score 0):

1. To deploy a website into IIS8 from Visual Studio, use 'File System' instead of 'Web Deploy', and put in the directory of where you want to publish your site.
2. Right-click your site name on your IIS 8 manager, select 'Add Application', and select the folder where you published your website in your physical path.
3. Click on the application under the website, then click browse, and you should view the website on your browser.

You can look at my question on how to create new website under the title, ['New website not showing default page in IIS 8.5'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38208465/new-website-not-showing-default-page-in-iis-8-5).