# New website not showing default page in IIS 8.5

Tags: windows, iis, windows-8.1, iis-8.5

I’m having trouble trying to view my default page or other web application on a newly created site (New Test Site) on IIS 8.5 for Windows 8.1.  I included a directory that contains an html page (test.html) outside of the ‘inetpub’ folder.

[Add website window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YwVG.jpg)

Physical Path:  C:\royalcenters
Type:  http
IP Address: All Unassigned
Port: 80

I already arranged the ‘test.html’ page to the top of the list of ‘Default Document’ tab.

[List of default pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWAuA.jpg)

However, when I ran the new website on a web browser, the page doesn’t appear.  It only shows an error page.

I’m trying to run the website with my computer as the server, so does anybody have any ideas on how to on how I can run the new website on my machine?  Thank you.

Comment: 1) what is the error you are getting?
2) it's better to embed the images in your question

Comment: When I browse the new website, it shows the server not found page.

Comment: Also, this is my first question asked on this site.  I can't embed images until I have 10 reputation points into my account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first things first goto http://localhost/ and see if it works. It should show the IIS Welcome page with version number. If you get a 503 error check if the default app pool is stopped for some reason. If other errors then need to fix those before proceeding to test your html page.

Try hosting that page under the site "Default Web Sites" that comes pre-built with IIS .  It uses the default port 80. So if you want to create your own site you need to use a different port number when you create that new site from IIS manager gui.

The default website typically points to a physical folder : c:\inetpub\wwwroot\

so copy your test.html page to the above folder and test by going to the URL : http://localhost/test.html

if it works then Try to create a new Web Site using directions from here (Step 2)  below. You can leave the hostname blank if you only intend to use the URL from your local PC. the url will be http://localhost:port/

http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/creating-websites/scenario-build-a-static-website-on-iis#02

**EDIT:**

so when you are at this screen when creating a new wesite :https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YwVG.jpg

do this :

1. Sitename = Site01
2. Apppool = DefaultAppPool (Make sure its started)
3. Physical path = C:\inetpub\Site01 -- Need to create and grant full rights to Everyone (for now but need to change later to a specific windows account )
4. Port : 8090
5. Hostname = Blank
6. Click Ok
7. Copy test.html to C:\inetpub\Site01
8. Browse to http://localhost:8090/test.html

Comment: I followed the instruction in the link you provided.  I opened the test page in 'Default Web Site', and it opens the test page.  It even works when I type in localhost in the browser.  After that, I created a new website, gave it a different port number other than 80, and it doesn't open the page.  I tried giving it different IP Addresses, and it still won't open.  I even changed the application pool to 'DefaultAppPool', and it still won't open the page.

Comment: you also need to copy that test.html page to the new directory which is mapped to the "NewWebsite" you just created. let me edit my post and add some more details

Comment: That helped alot.  Thanks a bunch on helpiong me view the new website.  I created a new web site, and created a new directory in the inetpub folder.  Then I copied the 'test.html' page into that new directory.  I browsed the page, and it opens the test page.  However, I want to add the custom host name, and view it on the browser.  Plus, do you know if it's possible to host a website in a different directory outside of the 'inetpub' folder?

Comment: @J.Zacka you are welcome ... yes it should be possible to create outside inetpub ... just try it out and see what happens, And about hostnames : you need to add that hostname to the DNS which I think will involve your networking or AD folks. On your side it is just entering it on step 5. Like : mysite.mydomian.com but it wont take effect untill the networking side of the configurations taken care of.